# Parametrization of $y^2=x^3$ to solve a line integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

Evaluate the following vector line integral given in differential form
$$\int_{\gamma} x^2y\,dx-xy\,dy$$
where $\gamma$ is the curve with equation $y^2=x^3$, from $(1,-1)$ to $(1,1)$. The textbook also says that a parametrization of $\gamma$ is $$\vec{r}(t)=(t^2,t^3),\ -1\le t\le 1$$
My question is: How do I find these parametrizations? I know how to parametrize lines in plane and space, but what about a curve such as $y^2=x^3$? Should I give $x$ any value depending on $t$ and then find $y$? For instance, $$x=t \rightarrow y=t^{3/2}$$ What about the interval in which $t$ varies?

Answer (score 1):

A rough sketch of the curve between start and end points may help.

[image]

As you can see, both start and end points $A(1,-1)$ and $B(1,1)$ have $x = 1$ but there are really two parts to the curve, one below x-axis and one above. A parametrization of $(t, t^{3/2})$ will only represent the curve above x-axis and you will need $(t, - t^{3/2})$ to cover the curve below x-axis. This will also mean, you will have to split your line integral in two parts.

i) $(t, - t^{3/2}), 0 \leq t \leq 1$ and your integral will have lower bound of $t=1$ and upper bound of $t = 0$.

ii) $(t, t^{3/2}), 0 \leq t \leq 1$ and your integral will have lower bound of $t=0$ and upper bound of $t = 1$.

That will ensure you line integral is along the curve from $A(1,-1)$ to $B(1,1)$.

But splitting a line integral for the same curve is not ideal and the parametrization $(t^2, t^3)$ addresses this issue because it represents your entire curve from $A$ to $B$ for $-1 \leq t \leq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the specific question:  "How do I find these parametrizations?", there is no general easy approach to turn a curve given by an implicit function into its parameterization.  The example you give is convenient and exceptional in that there is a simple algebraic expression for the required path which takes advantage of the fact that $y = t^3$ has real continuous root for all real $y$.  Your proposal of taking $x=t$ would also work with the caveat you then need to break the path $\gamma$ into two components, one with a plus sign and the other with a minus sign. You can force the parameter to run from $[-1,1]$ by manipulating the argument, for example,
\begin{align}
(x,y) = \left\{ \begin{aligned}
&(t, t^{3/2}), &t \in[0,1]  \\ &(-t, -(-t)^{3/2}), & t \in[-1,0].
\end{aligned} \right.
\end{align}
You would then need to break the integral(s) into two, one over each sub-range.

If your implicit function had been $y^2 = x^4$ the path has potential for multiple branches, of which just one passes through your given points, and it's parameterization would need two expressions, one for negative $y$ and one for positive $y$, mushc as above.  For example,
\begin{align}(x,y) =  \left\{ \begin{aligned}
&(t,t^2), & t\in[0,1]  \\ &(-t, -t^2), &t\in[-1,0].
\end{aligned} \right. 
\end{align}
In general implicit functions can describe a multitude of curves:  consider a product
\begin{align}
f_1(x,y) f_2(x,y) \cdots f_n(x,y) = 0
\end{align}
where, with luck, each $f_n$ might describe a single and distinct curve but then the product describes $n$ curves.

When faced with the problem of finding a parametric form for some branch of an implicit function, it's useful to sketch the curve(s) if you can.  To do that, if not obvious, you can try solving the implicit function, $y$ in terms of $x$ or vice versa, but also be ready to apply your own a repertoire of possible substitutions and transformations (e.g. using polar coordinates) .